# Why sinatra running in docker require tty option for logging at main?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7-alpine
RUN gem install sinatra
```

```
$ docker build -t sinatra .
```

test.rb

```rb
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT, level: :info)
logger.info 'log before sinatra'
puts 'puts before sinatra'

require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end

logger.info 'log after sinatra'
puts 'puts after sinatra'
```

Without -t option, puts and logger.info print nothing til interupted by C-c.

```
$ docker run --rm -v$PWD:/app sinatra ruby /app/test.rb
[2020-10-11 11:48:20] INFO  WEBrick 1.6.0
[2020-10-11 11:48:20] INFO  ruby 2.7.1 (2020-03-31) [x86_64-linux-musl]
== Sinatra (v2.1.0) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2020-10-11 11:48:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4567
```

With -t option, they print as they go.

```
$ docker run -t --rm -v$PWD:/app sinatra ruby /app/test.rb
I, [2020-10-11T11:48:41.216144 #1]  INFO -- : log before sinatra
puts before sinatra
I, [2020-10-11T11:48:41.553242 #1]  INFO -- : log after sinatra
puts after sinatra
I, [2020-10-11T11:48:41.555356 #1]  INFO -- : before sinatra
I, [2020-10-11T11:48:41.557748 #1]  INFO -- : after sinatra
[2020-10-11 11:48:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.6.0
[2020-10-11 11:48:41] INFO  ruby 2.7.1 (2020-03-31) [x86_64-linux-musl]
== Sinatra (v2.1.0) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2020-10-11 11:48:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4567
```

What happen there?

EDIT: If commented sinatra related lines out, like this;

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT, level: :info)
logger.info 'log before sinatra'
puts 'puts before sinatra'

# require 'sinatra'
# get '/' do
#   'Hello world!'
# end

logger.info 'log after sinatra'
puts 'puts after sinatra'
```

Logs and puts are printed as expected without `-t` option.

```
$ docker run  --rm -v$PWD:/app sinatra ruby /app/test.rb  
I, [2020-10-12T23:54:28.138590 #1]  INFO -- : log before sinatra
puts before sinatra
I, [2020-10-12T23:54:28.138678 #1]  INFO -- : log after sinatra
puts after sinatra
```

Comment: You are telling the logger to log to STDOUT and the STDOUT comes with the tty.

Comment: Thansk for you comment, but could you elaborate this? docker run -t option is explained as `Allocate a pseudo-TTY`.  I think it doesn't do for streaming output to stdout.

Comment: I suspect this is due to buffering the output. What happens if you add `$stdout.sync = true` to the beginning of your Ruby script?

Comment: I did try sync but no luck. Also Logger did it. I forgot to mention that I suspect that Logger use monitor.synchronize to write logs to create critical section for multithreaded use.

Answer (score 0):

If you log to STDOUT it seems that the logger is detecting STDOUT via the tty. Like described in https://jameshfisher.com/2017/12/09/what-is-a-tty/

The docker documentation aims in the same direction:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground

#### Foreground

In foreground mode (the default when `-d` is not specified), `docker run` can start the process in the container and attach the console to
the process's standard input, output, and standard error. It can even
pretend to be a TTY (this is what most command line executables expect)
and pass along signals. All of that is configurable:

```
-a=[]           : Attach to `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and/or `STDERR`
-t              : Allocate a pseudo-tty
--sig-proxy=true: Proxy all received signals to the process (non-TTY mode only)
-i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

If you do not specify `-a` then Docker will [attach to both stdout and stderr](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/4118e0c9eebda2412a09ae66e90c34b85fae3275/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L267)
.
You can specify to which of the three standard streams (`STDIN`, `STDOUT`,
`STDERR`) you'd like to connect instead, as in:

```sh
$ docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks, but still I don't understand what make difference outputs in my examples. I edited to add a case without sinatra.